# How to add multiple linkout suggestion cards in google dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I need help figuring out how to add multiple linkout suggestion cards in one intent. Is there a way I can add multiple clickable links in google dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

You'are tring add more 'Text Response'?
If yes just do this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIyGJ.png)